# MyBatis when converting #{} element, redundant ' show up?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, mybatis

I am using MyBatis to do sql query, here is the mapper file:

```
  <select id="getDepByIdVersion"  resultMap="BaseResultMap">
    select
    <include refid="Base_Column_List" />
    from dependencies where id = #{repo_id} AND version = #{version_id} </select>
```

while converting "#{version_id}", strange things happened ———— redundant single quote ' shows up：

```
2020-05-29 20:24:00.483  INFO 10684 --- [io-18080-exec-2] c.z.n.controller.RepoInfoController      : repo_id:1123
2020-05-29 20:24:00.483  INFO 10684 --- [io-18080-exec-2] c.z.n.controller.RepoInfoController      : version_id:1.0.0
2020-05-29 20:24:00.508  INFO 10684 --- [io-18080-exec-2] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2020-05-29 20:24:00.663  INFO 10684 --- [io-18080-exec-2] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2020-05-29 20:24:00.663 DEBUG 10684 --- [io-18080-exec-2] c.z.n.d.D.getDepByIdVersion              : ==>  Preparing: select id, version, dep_name, constraint from dependencies where id = ? AND version = ? 
2020-05-29 20:24:00.695 DEBUG 10684 --- [io-18080-exec-2] c.z.n.d.D.getDepByIdVersion              : ==> Parameters: 1123(String), 1.0.0(String)
2020-05-29 20:24:00.806 ERROR 10684 --- [io-18080-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: 
### Error querying database.  Cause: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'constraint

    from dependencies where id = '1123' AND version = '1.0.0'' at line 3
### The error may exist in file [J:\Programming\NpmGraph\target\classes\mapper\DependenciesMapper.xml]
### The error may involve defaultParameterMap
### The error occurred while setting parameters
### SQL: select           id, version, dep_name, constraint         from dependencies where id = ? AND version = ?
### Cause: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'constraint

    from dependencies where id = '1123' AND version = '1.0.0'' at line 3
; bad SQL grammar []; nested exception is java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'constraint

    from dependencies where id = '1123' AND version = '1.0.0'' at line 3] with root cause
```

You can see from above, the original is 1.0.0, while after conversion it becomes '1.0.0''.
Anybody know why?

Comment: Your log messages don't match the SQL fragment you are showing. When you use `#{}` it should be converted to `?` in the executed SQL. Is there a fragment like `'${}''` somewhere in your XML?

Comment: The quote is just added in the error message. The problem is the column name constraint which is a reserved keyword. Enclosing the column name with backticks should fix the problem.

Comment: I think ave is right!!! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe it's because the column constraint, i'll check it out.